# Can't translate foreach from C# to Java

Tags: java, c#, search-engine, key-value, code-translation

I'm trying to translate a [Boolean Retrieval Model search engine](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=375219) and can't translate this piece of code to Java.

C#:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string ,List<string>> p in documentCollection){}
```

Java:

```
for(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> p : documentCollection){}
```

Unfortunately Java giving me this error:

> for-each not applicable to application type

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the definition of documentCollection ?

Comment: @rapharel documentCollection  should be instance of java.lang.Iterable or array

Comment: @JFPicard public static Map<Integer, List<String>> documentCollection = new HashMap<>();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between the way a collection interface is implemented by C#'s `IDictionary<K,V>` and Java's `Map<K,V>`. In C#, the collection itself can be enumerated for key-value pairs; in Java, you must call a method to obtain a key-value set, which is called [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()):

```
for (Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>> p : documentCollection.entrySet()) {
    ...
}
```

Note that in Java you iterate `Map.Entry<K,V>` objects instead of C#'s `KeyValuePair<K,V>`.